# Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\edit.php on line 13

Tags: php, mysql

The given code is a demonstration of crud operation in PHP.

the basic HTML form has three field `NAME`, `EMAIl`, `DEPT`, and a submit button.

the  basic operations are working fine add delete and form submission but when I want to update the data it gave

> Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\edit.php on line 13.

but when I changed the query in my edit.php filed id to name it will work fine but it is not working when a change the name to id in my query in edit.php file 
the table name is `crud`. and `id` is the primary key in the table. the id is auto incremented.
I don't understand why it is working with name and not to work with id filed.

```
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>CRUD</title>
        </head>
        <style type="text/css">
            form{
                text-align: center;
                margin-top:50px; 
                font-family:serif;
                color: grey;
            }
            input{
                margin:10px;
            }

        </style>
        <body>

        <form action="submit.php" method="POST">
            ID:<input type="text" name="id" style="width:200px"; disabled required placeholder="Autogenrated">
            <br>
            Name:<input type="text" name="name"  style="width:200px";required><br>
            email:<input type="email" name="email"  style="width:200px";required><br>
            Dept:<input type="text" name="dept" style="width:200px"; required><br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit" style="width:80px";>Submit</button>
        </form>
        </div>
        </body>
        </html>

        <?php 
        include_once('db.php');
        if (isset($_GET['edit'])){
            $id=$_GET['edit'];
            $sql=$conn->query("select * from crud where id=$id");
            while($row=$sql->fetch_array()){
                $name=$row['name'];
                $email=$row['email'];
                $dept=$row['dept'];
            }
        }
        if (isset($_POST['update'])){
            $id=$_POST['id'];
            echo $id ;  
        }

        ?>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            ID:<input type="text" name="id" value="<?php echo $id ?>" style="width:200px"; disabled required placeholder="Autogenrated" >
            <br>
            Name:<input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name ?>" style="width:200px";required><br>
            email:<input type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" style="width:200px";required><br>
            Dept:<input type="text" name="dept" value="<?php echo $dept ?>" style="width:200px"; required><br>
            <button type="submit" name="update" style="width:80px";>Update</button>


        </form>
        <?php

        include_once('db.php');
        if (isset($_GET['del'])) {
            $id=$_GET['del'];

            $sql="delete from crud where id='$id'";
            mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
        }


        header('Location:display.php');
        ?>
        <?php 

        include_once('db.php');
        $sql="select * from crud";
        $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                echo "--Name:".$row["name"]."--Email:".$row["email"]." "."--dept:".$row["dept"].""; 
        echo "<br>";
                echo '<td><a href="edit.php?edit=' . $row['id'] . '">Edit</a></td>';

        echo '<td><a href="delete.php?del=' . $row['id'] . '">Delete</a></td>';
        echo "<br>";
        echo '<td><a href="index.php?">add</a></td>';echo "<br>";

            }

        }


         ?>

        <?php 
        $hostname="localhost";
        $user="root";
        $pass="";
        $dbname="test";
        $conn=mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$pass,$dbname);
         ?>
```

Comment: Your method is POST not GET and the name of the isset is edit instead update

Comment: but how it will work with the name instead of id

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
if (isset($_POST['update'])){
            $id=$_POST['id'];
            echo $id ;  
        }
```

to

```
if (isset($_POST['update'],$_POST['id'])){
            $id=$_POST['id'];
            echo $id ;  
        }
```